# Get an accurate return code from beeline when using an HQL file?

Tags: hive, beeline

I have an init file and a HQL file that I am passing to beeline to execute:

```
beeline -i "$INIT_FILE" -f "$BEELINE_HQL_FILE"
```

And I want beeline to stop executing the script and return an error code if there are any lines in the script that failed. However, if there are errors in the script, then it continues executing and returns 0 as the return code. 
How can I configure it to do what I want?

Comment: it is a better idea to have one file per query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [HS2 Clients Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-BeelineCommandOptions):

> --force=[true/false]   Continue running script even after errors (true) or do not continue (false). Default is false.
>
> Usage: beeline --force=true

So, by default beeline would stop executing a script in case of an error. If it behaves different in your environment, maybe you can try using `$ beeline --force=false ...`

**Update**

Beeline will return a non-zero return code when it fails to execute an HQL statement or script.

```
$ beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10000/default;" -e "describe unknown_table"
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Table not found unknown_table (state=42S02,code=10001)

$ echo $?
1
$
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue where the script continues, but does not fix the part where beeline reports a success code on failure

Comment: It appears to only return a non-zero return code if you are using the `-e` option, but for some reason not the `-f` option

Comment: It does, for both `-e` and `-f`, as long as you're able to connect to HS2 and failure occurs executing some SQL.

Comment: Looks like it was not detecting the error code because I was checking the wrong variable -_-

Comment: for me using -e returned always 0,  with --force=false it now returns finally 1