# Check if any hive table is missing from hql file in shell

Tags: shell, unix, hive, hql

I Have a requirement to check if ant table is missing from the hql file while the beeline query is getting executed from shell script!

Example :

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://server.domain.<>.com:10000/default;principal=hive/server.domain.com@SERVER.DOMAIN.COM' -f filename.hql
```

In `filename.hql` we have 10 tables and 9 of them got executed while there is a failure of one table.

In this case what can be the possible solution . I am not able to figure it out via a shell script?

Can somenone please help?

Comment: Can you use a transaction to make sure either all or none of the changes are applied? Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1043554/10622916

Comment: No we do not have permission for this

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about all your requirements or restrictions. You could run the query on a test server first before using it on the real server.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552179/get-an-accurate-return-code-from-beeline-when-using-an-hql-file

Comment: But @Raid if there are multiple table in hql file how to detect missing table?